# Risks associated with switching ISPs/Telco providers

Tags: risk-management, risk

What are the risks associated with switching Internet Service Providers and/or Telco providers (i.e. Telstra -> Optus), if any?

This is in relation to a larger organisation with a wide area network.

Comment: The only thing I currently can think of is the new IP addresses you'll get could be black-listed on some RBL. In addition to that I can see that switching might cause outage to certain systems.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I didn't think of that. 


The topic of blocked IP addresses made me think of an additional issue. Telstra might have a list of blocked IP addresses that prevent SPAM from reaching customers. Optus would probably have a similar list, but there is a possibility it differs greatly to Telstra. So switching IP providers might result in greater susceptibility to SPAM and attacks in general?

Comment: @KimberlyK: Yes, that's my thought. Although the likelihood is small. Can't you contact Telstra and discuss this with them? Or ask them which block you'll get, so you can do some research?